# Windows 10 'forgets' VPN connection

Tags: windows-10, vpn

So I have a Windows 10 laptop. There I have a PPTP VPN connection set up.

From time to time, this connection disappears from the networking pane, and it's not found anywhere so I have to recreate it, which is annoying. Disappears as if deleted.

Most often it happens after Windows installs updates.

How to diagnose/prevent that?

Comment: Could you provide any more information? Are you using a VPN client? Do you have any other applications that edit network settings? Can you run a virus scan?

Comment: @Cancun101 using VPN built-in in Windows. No other applications are used. Virus scan is an interesting proposition which I would entertain.

Comment: Any news on that virus scan?

Comment: I ran Malwarebytes, they didn't find anything relevant.